# How to remove duplicates rows from foundry fusion sheets

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-fusion-sheet

How to remove duplicate rows from foundry fusion sheets?

For example:

| Department | course |
| --- | --- |
| CSE | python |
| CSE | java |
| CSE | python |
| IT | java |
| CSE | java |
| IT | java |

then after removing duplicates expected output would be:

| Department | course |
| --- | --- |
| CSE | python |
| CSE | java |
| IT | java |

Answer (score 1):

Foundry fusion is not a data transformation tool, so the short answer is you can't.

If you need to do these types of filtering and manipulation, there are plenty of other tools in the platform that let you manipulate data: Contour, Transforms, ...